# How can I reuse a gethash lookup in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a hash table where the keys are rather complex lists, with sublists of symbols and integers, and the value should be modified depending on the already existing value. The table is created with `:test #'equal`.

I do something similar to this a lot:

```
(defun try-add (i)
  (let ((old-i (gethash complex-list table nil)))
    (if (may-add old-i)
      (push i (gethash complex-list table)))))
```

Profiling shows that `equal` tests take a lot of time. I have an optimization idea, that the amount of `gethash` lookups could be reduced from two to one. It can be done in C++ by reusing the iterator, but not sure how this would be done in Lisp. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't do anything special, because the implementation does it for you.

Of course, this approach is implementation-specific, and hash table performance varies between implementations.  (But then optimization questions are always implementation-specific.)

The following answer is for SBCL.  I recommend checking whether your Lisp's hash tables perform the same optimization.  Complain to your vendor if they don't!

What happens in SBCL is that **the hash table caches the last table index** accessed by GETHASH.

When PUTHASH (or equivalently, (SETF GETHASH)) is called, it first checks whether the key at that cached index is EQ to the key that you are passing in.

If so, the entire hash table lookup routine is by-passed, and PUTHASH stores directly at the cached index.

Note that EQ is just a pointer comparison and hence extremely fast -- it does not have to traverse the list at all.

So in your code example, the is no overhead at all.

Comment: It seems we can thank Paul F. Dietz: http://git.boinkor.net/gitweb/sbcl.git/commitdiff/bc1783335d78be988465e4fc7cf9c5fdb88a3fa4

Comment: What is `PUTHASH`? I did not find any mentions of `PUTHASH` in the Common Lisp HyperSpec.

Answer (score 1):

You may actually be accessing the hash table three times. Why? Because the `push` macro may expand into code that does a `gethash` to get the list, and then some `system::sethash` operation to store the value.

In this problem, you are inspecting the value of a place, which is a list. If that list satisfies some predicate test, then you push something onto that place.

This problem can be attacked by creating special-purpose operator which captures this semantics:

```
 (push-if <new-value> <predicate> <place>)
```

For instance:

```
 (push-if i #'may-add (gethash complex-list table))
```

This `push-if` is defined as a macro which uses the `get-setf-expansion` function on the `<place>` form argument to obtain the pieces needed to generate the code to access that place just once.

The generated code evaluates a load form to get the old value from the place, then applies the condition to the old value, and if it succeeds, then it prepares the new value in the appropriate temporary store variable obtained from `get-setf-expansion` and evaluates the store form.

This is the best you can do in portable Lisp, and you may find that this still performs two hash operations, as mentioned above. (In which case you hope there is a decent caching optimization in the hash table itself. But at least it is down to two ops.)

The approach will be as optimized as the built in place mutating forms: `incf`, `push`, `rotatef`, etc. Our `push-if` will be on par with the built-ins.

If it still sucks (performs two hashes to update a hash place, with no caching optimization), then the only way to fix that is at the implementation level.

`push-if` code follows:

```
(defmacro push-if (new-value predicate-fun list-place &environment env)
  (multiple-value-bind (temp-syms val-forms
                        store-vars store-form access-form)
                       (get-setf-expansion list-place env)
    (let ((old-val (gensym)))
      (when (rest store-vars)
        (error "PUSH-IF: cannot take ref of multiple-value place"))
      `(multiple-value-bind (,@temp-syms) (values ,@val-forms)
         (let ((,old-val ,access-form))
           (when (funcall ,predicate-fun ,old-val)
             (setf ,(first store-vars) (cons ,new-value ,old-val))
             ,store-form))))))
```

Sample expansion:

```
> (macroexpand '(push-if new test place))
(LET* ((#:VALUES-12731 (MULTIPLE-VALUE-LIST (VALUES))))
 (LET ((#:G12730 PLACE))
  (WHEN (FUNCALL TEST #:G12730) (SETF #:NEW-12729 (CONS NEW #:G12730))
   (SETQ PLACE #:NEW-12729)))) ;
```

Looks sane for the simple case when the place is a variable. There is only a slight problem that I'm not going to fix: the forms `new`, `test` and `place` are evaluated just once each, but not in left-to-right order!

Test with a hash table place (CLISP):

```
> (macroexpand '(push-if new test (gethash a b)))
(LET*
 ((#:VALUES-12736 (MULTIPLE-VALUE-LIST (VALUES A B)))
  (#:G12732 (POP #:VALUES-12736)) (#:G12733 (POP #:VALUES-12736)))
 (LET ((#:G12735 (GETHASH #:G12732 #:G12733)))
  (WHEN (FUNCALL TEST #:G12735) (SETF #:G12734 (CONS NEW #:G12735))
   (SYSTEM::PUTHASH #:G12732 #:G12733 #:G12734)))) ;
```

Aha; now there is somewhat more interesting code being generated in order to avoid evaluating `a` and `b` twice. The `gethash` function is invoked once, but its arguments are gensym variables. The old value is captured as `#:G12735`. The test is applied to it, and if it passes, the store variabel `#:G12734` is updated with a the old list value with `new` consed in front of it. Then, that value is put into the hash table with `system::puthash`.

So in this Lisp implementation, there is no way to avoid two hash table operations to perform an update: `gethash` and `system::puthash`. This is the best we can do and hope that the two work as an optimized pair.

Answer (score 0):

Some workarounds might be:

If the common pattern is lookup -> find-it -> overwrite-it, then you could replace the value type to a list that contains the value type. Then after finding the value object for the key, just destructively replace its first element, e.g.

```
(defun try-add (i)
  (let ((old-i-list (gethash complex-list table nil)))
    (if (may-add (first old-i-list))
      (setf (first old-i-list) i)                     ; overwrite without searching again
      (setf (gethash complex-list table) (list i))))) ; not there? too bad, we have to gethash again
```

Alternatively, if the common pattern is more like lookup -> it's-not-there -> add-it, you might want to consider hashing the keys on your own, and then have the hash table use your hashed value as the key. This might be more complicated, depending on the depth and semantics of these complex lists. In the simple case, you might get away with a hash function that (recursively) xor's the hash value of the elements of its list argument.

---

EDITED: answering the question in the comments: the idea is that instead of the hash table mapping keys to values, the hash table will now map keys to single element lists, where the element is the value. Then you can change the contents of these lists without touching the hash table itself. The following is from SBCL:

```
* (defparameter *my-hash* (make-hash-table))
*MY-HASH*

* (setf (gethash :my-key *my-hash*) (list "old-value"))
("old-value")

* (gethash :my-key *my-hash*)
("old-value")
T

* (defparameter old-value-container (gethash :my-key *my-hash*))
OLD-VALUE-CONTAINER

* (setf (first old-value-container) "new value")
"new value"

* (gethash :my-key *my-hash*)
("new value")
T
```

Comment: I tried something similar to the source code you posted, but when doing the (setf (first old-i-list)...), it only alters old-i-list and the change is not reflected in the hash table value. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Comment: @kotlinski: If you did that where the initial value of old-i-list is nil, then yes, that's not going to be reflected in the value in the hash table.  However, if you did have a list there already, then gethash returns the list and you can mutate it in the way you're thinking of.

Note, "push" won't work because that affects the variable you're pushing onto, adding a new head & setting the variable to point to that new value.  It will then share part of the list with the hashtable value (assuming that's not nil), but not be the same.

Comment: "Common lisp's built in data structures are notoriously opaque." -- what do you mean?

Comment: The discussion at http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/7sab5/problems_with_lisp_hash_tables/ demonstrates some of the criticisms. This is not an attack on the language, but rather an observation on how some of its built in construct are architected. I'm removing the notoriety note though -- it's not adding value to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use defstruct to create a value which every entry in your hash table points to.  Your list of values (that you're pushing onto in your current example) could be stored inside there.  The struct creation could either be done in that initial gethash call (as the default value), or could be done manually if you observe there's no value there.  Then, the object can be side-effected in the way that you're doing.

(This ignores the question of whether or not you really want to be using such complex values as your hashtable keys, or if there's a way to work around that.  For example, you could be using structures/CLOS objects instead of complex lists as your keys, and then you could use an EQ hashtable instead.  But that depends a lot on what you're doing.)

Answer (score 0):

"Profiling shows that equal tests take a long of time."

Yes, but have you verified that #'EQUAL *hash table lookups* do also take a lot of time?

Have you compiled this for speed on an optimizing compiler like SBCL and looked at the compiler notes?

After having resolved these two questions you could also try a nested hash table for each level of your list keys. It should not be hard to write a macro for arbitrarily nested hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but:

```
(defun try-add (i)
  (let ((old-i (gethash complex-list table)))
    (when (may-add old-i)
      (push i old-i))))
```

since:

- nil is already the default for GETHASH
- GETHASH pulls out the whole object so you can just modify it in-place rather than telling PUSH how to look it up again
- (style point: use WHEN instead of IF when there's no else-clause)

Edit: oops, I was: I missed the case where old-i is nil.  But if that's not the common case, then it still might be a win, since you only need to do the lookup in that case:

```
(defun try-add (i)
  (let ((old-i (gethash complex-list table)))
    (when (may-add old-i)
      (if old-i
         (push i old-i)
        (push i (gethash complex-list table))))))
```

Hmm, does that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You're pushing items onto the `old-i` place which has no effect on what is stored in the `(gethash ...)` place, since non-empty Lisp lists are pointers to a head node, and not containers.