# Avoiding redundant place calculations with setf

Tags: common-lisp

## The Context

I've found in my limited experience with Common Lisp, it's not uncommon to have some code like this

```
(setf (gethash key table)
      (my-transformation (gethash key table)))
```

where you read from a `setf`able place, perform some computation on the value stored there, then write to the same place. The thing I don't like about this is that the place will be computed twice, but the place will (hopefully!) be the same both times. If the place computation is expensive, we're doing as much as twice as much work as we need to.

## The Question

Is it possible to eliminate the need for the double computation? That is, is it possible (desirable?) to write a macro `setf-inplace`:

```
(setf-inplace (gethash key table) #'my-transformation)
```

conceptually equivalent (ignoring for the moment `multiple-values` weirdness) to but potentially much faster than the original code, preferably without relying on implementation details?

I know I may be putting the cart in front of the horse in this particular case, since [SBCL caches the lookup for `gethash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099509/how-can-i-reuse-a-gethash-lookup-in-common-lisp), but it seems to me that other `setf`able places, like `(assoc key my-alist)`, may not be so easy to cache—except, of course, via some mechanism like the `setf-inplace` above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(setf (gethash key table)
      (my-transformation (gethash key table)))
```

Let's say the transformation is `1+`. Then above is

```
(setf (gethash key table)
      (1+ (gethash key table)))
```

Which in Common Lisp has a macro:

```
(incf (gethash key table))
```

Clozure CL expands this to:

```
(LET* ((#:G69020 KEY)
       (#:G69021 TABLE)
       (#:G69022 1)
       (#:G69019 (+ (GETHASH #:G69020 #:G69021) #:G69022)))
  (DECLARE (TYPE BIT #:G69022) (TYPE T #:G69019))
  (CCL::PUTHASH #:G69020 #:G69021 #:G69019))
```

Now remember that the setter for a place is found at compile time and that the setter operation of a place is different from the getter. Not only does the setter something different by updating something, but it also may do arbitrary other things like setting up a transaction, acquiring a lock, ... Thus getting and setting are not the same/similar operation twice.

Common Lisp has no physical data structure which represents a place. A place is an abstract idea which combines a setter with a given getter. The setter can be arbitrary complex code.

So, in above code - which calculations are redundant?

Still you say what about optimizing access for the primitive case:

```
(incf (car (very-long-access-chain data)))
```

You would have to write by hand:

```
(let ((cons-cell (very-long-access-chain data)))
  (incf (car cons-cell))
```

Which is basically what Lisp does anyway. See: CLHS [5.1.1.1 Evaluation of Subforms to Places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aaa.htm)

Comment: I don't see anything gained by moving the very-long-access-chain out of the incf into a let in the last example, it seems to me (and my macroexpander) that the only difference between the two forms is an extra lexical binding. Am I missing the point?

Comment: That makes sense; I hadn't realized that the getter and setter were possibly unrelated computations. In fact, looking at SBCL's `SB!IMPL:GETHASH` et al., there's not much if any code shared between the implementations. Still, it seems to me that it should be possible, for example, to define a setf-expander that caches the "place" in its temporary variables. In that case, such a macro as `setf-inplace` should be workable. I don't know if it would be possible, though, to write it to do anything sensible with non-caching setf-expanders.

Comment: @Stuart Olsen: you can't catch a place. It does not exist. A place is not a pointer or a data-structure you can store. That's the problem.

Comment: @m-n: yes, that was misleading. Changed.

Comment: When I say "place," I mean some structure which stores a reference to the thing being manipulated. It doesn't matter what it is as long as the getter knows how to bind it to an expander temporary and the setter knows how to retrieve the reference from that temporary. A key (no pun intended) factor in whether `setf-inplace` is possible is whether it is necessary for `setf-inplace` to be able to understand that structure, or whether it is sufficient for the setf-expander to understand it. I suspect that the latter is the case, but I haven't played enough with it to know for sure.

Comment: @Stuart Olsen: This reference does not exist in Common Lisp.

Comment: @RainerJoswig A pair is a structure which stores a reference—two, in fact. `(cons my-object nil)` and equivalent constructs are perfectly suitable for representing references, as long as you remember to write your code to look through the `car` for the object proper. When we're just talking about one getter, one setter, and _maybe_ the theoretical `setf-inplace` needing to worry about such a construct, it seems feasible to me to do things this way.

Comment: @Stuart Olsen: a pair is not a structure which necessary stores a reference. `(cons 3 nil)`. The three is not a reference. `(let ((foo some-object)) (list (cons foo nil) (cons foo nil)))`. If some-object is a fixnum, it will be stored inline. If some-object is an array, a reference will be stored and both references will point to the same object. A cons can also not point into a hash-table, a complex number, a vector, a string, nor into an abstract object, ...

Comment: The setf mechanism is cool, but I don't think it can do what the OP desires.  Consider (incf (getf :key place 0)).  As far as I know, it is not possible to write your setf method for getf such that you avoid seaching the property list in value twice.  Meanwhile setf isn't thread safe, so while that's interesting it's a distraction.

Comment: @RainerJoswig That's not quite correct; a pair does always hold references, even to numbers (e.g., the car of `(cons 3 nil)` is semantically a reference to _the_ (immutable) number 3, even if the reference isn't actually represented as a pointer. That's why equal numbers compare `eq`). The reason my cons-boxing doesn't work in general is that when you `cons x nil`, the car of the pair is bound to the _referent_ of x, and so you can't rebind x through it. It only works if, as in hash-maps, x itself is a cons whose field(s) you want to rebind.

Comment: @StuartOlsen Rather, equal numbers compare `eql`, which "tells whether two objects are conceptually the same, whereas eq tells whether two objects are implementationally identical." I suppose cons-boxing might work where x is an array, too, but the bottom line is that it's probably not as generally applicable a solution as I originally thought.

Comment: @StuartOlsen: one of the problems is that the getter/setter mechanism is completely independent of memory references. The getter could get the state of some process on the network and the setter sets that process. `(get-floor elevator)` and `(setf (get-floor elevator) 4)` - nothing to cache...

Comment: @StuartOlsen: see this: the Lisp Machine had a form of pointer concept: Locatives. http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/mit/cadr/chinual_5thEd_Jan83/chinualJan83_13_Locatives.pdf

Comment: @RainerJoswig To the first comment, of course; but I'm interested specifically in the special case those setf-expanders which can be written to use a reference, such as `(setf gethash)`, which could conceivably store a temporary reference to the internal `(key . value)` pair if it's implemented that way. In the general case, you can always fall back to `(setf (get-floor elevator) (my-transform (get-floor elevator))`. At any rate, the CADR manual should be a good read, whatever it has to say on this topic.

Comment: @StuartOlsen: As far as I have heard, that kind of caching optimization is actually automatically done by Lisp compilers.